# Map left command key to left control key in terminal only?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, vi, karabiner

I'm using neovim to edit code and am needing to create a mapping in which I press the **left command key**, and neovim *(or at least my alacritty terminal)* thinks that I am pressing the **left control key**.

I of course would love for neovim to be able to recognize the **command key on mac** but I can't seem to find any way to do this.

I have tried writing a karabiner-elements rule that applies **only when editing in neovim** without any success.

Would someone be able to show me the correct way to write an application-specific keybinding in karabiner elements that only functions in neovim? Or if there is any way in which I may use the command key natively in neovim?

- macOS: **Catalina 10.15.7**
- Terminal: **Alacritty@latest**
- neovim: **v0.4.4**
- karabiner-elements-**@latest**

Comment: Did you see this reddit comment https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/2tbn15/cmd_key_binding/cnxz3q4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: or this github issue https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/7721#issue-281255962

Comment: @theonlygusti Yes, I tried the first thing google shows me when I search for this problem.

Comment: @theonlygusti neither of those threads provide any insight into the issue. Just that they have the same issue.

Comment: if `map <D-x>` doesn't map cmd-x in neovim for you, it means your terminal is capturing the command key and not letting neovim hear it

Comment: @theonlygusti yeah that's what I figured. I have no custom key bindings set up in my terminal or on my mac; it doesn't seem to matter which combo of <D-...> I use. Neovim isn't passed the instruction.

Comment: @theonlygusti this is the only key mapping I need to use for cmd in neovim `nmap <D> <C-w>`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you didn't post WHAT exactly you wrote in your Karabiner-elements rule. Here is what normally works for specific apps:

There comes an app EventViewer with Karabiner-Elements that in its tab "Frontmost application" shows information on any active applications.
E.g., it might return "com.apple.TextEdit" and you would write in Karabiner:

```
{   "conditions": [
   {
      "bundle_identifiers": [
          "^com.apple.TextEdit" ],
      "type": "frontmost_application_if"
   }             ]
```

(Notice the ^ -character.) If you haven't tried it this way it might help.